# Angular Filters: How to pre-filter so angular filters consider only a partial of the whole data object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options, angular-filters

I got a large data table (which gets its data from a json api) with multiple columns and would like to implement multiple filters doing the following:

1. an option to select which data-column should be considered (a dropdown containing the thead option) [my columnFilter]
   and then
2. an input field to filter that particular data-partial [my searchFilter]

I've got the searchFilter working, but I'm not sure how to connect the columnFilter and make the searchFilter only apply to the selected data-partial.

So let's say I'd like to only see Descriptions containing the world "blue".

How can I bind these two filters and make this work?

Here is some of my code:

```
  Select data column:
  <select ng-model="columnFilter" ng-options="heading for heading in headings">
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
   Filter selection: <input type='text' ng-model="searchFilter" />
</div>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>URL</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Traffic</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>ID</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="url in urls | filter:searchFilter">
    <tr>
      <td>{{url.url}}</td>
      <td>{{url.title}}</td>
      <td>{{url.traffic}}</td>
      <td>{{url.descr}}</td>
      <td>{{url.id}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and a link to a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/TddllGiey0RmCx18eVdd?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know angular, there is two main way to solve your problem.

1. define a custom a filter
2. define a function to filter your data and call it with ng-show or ng-hide

> I got a large data table

If i understand well, you specify that because performance is a big issue.

There is a good article which exposes the differences between those two solutions : http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2487-filter-vs-nghide-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs.htm

As performance may be really important for you, i suggest you the second approach.

In your view:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="url in urls" ng-show="filterUrl(url)">
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.searchFilter = "";
$scope.columnFilter = $scope.headings[5];

$scope.filterUrl = function(url){ 
  if(!$scope.searchFilter || $scope.searchFilter == "")
    return url;
  var searchFilter= $scope.searchFilter.toLowerCase();
  var trafficString = url.traffic.toString();
  var idString = url.traffic.toString();
  switch($scope.columnFilter){
    case $scope.headings[0]:
      return url.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchFilter) != -1;
    case $scope.headings[1]:
      return url.url.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchFilter) != -1;
    case $scope.headings[2]:
      return trafficString.indexOf(searchFilter) != -1;
    case $scope.headings[3]:
      return url.descr.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchFilter) != -1;
    case $scope.headings[4]:
      return idString.indexOf(searchFilter) != -1;
    case $scope.headings[5]: 
      return url.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchFilter) != -1 ||
      url.url.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchFilter) != -1 ||
      trafficString.indexOf(searchFilter) != -1 ||
      url.descr.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchFilter) != -1 ||
      idString.indexOf(searchFilter) != -1;
  }
};
```

Update:
If you choose the first approach:

In your view:

```
 <tbody ng-repeat="url in urls | filterByColumn: searchFilter :columnFilter">
```

The filter:

```
app.filter('filterByColumn', function(){
  return function(urls, text, columnFilter){
    var processed = [];
     if(!text || text == "")
        return urls;
    urls.forEach(function(url){
      var searchFilter= text.toLowerCase();
      var trafficString = url.traffic.toString();
      var idString = url.traffic.toString();
      switch(columnFilter){
        case "Title":
          if( url.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchFilter) != -1)
            processed.push(url);
          break;
        case "Url":
          if(url.url.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchFilter) != -1)
            processed.push(url);
          break;
        case "Traffic":
          if(trafficString.indexOf(searchFilter) != -1)
            processed.push(url);
          break;
        case "Description":
          if(url.descr.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchFilter) != -1)
            processed.push(url);
          break;
        case "Id":
          if( idString.indexOf(searchFilter) != -1)
            processed.push(url);
          break;
        case "All": 
          if( url.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchFilter) != -1 ||
          url.url.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchFilter) != -1 ||
          trafficString.indexOf(searchFilter) != -1 ||
          url.descr.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchFilter) != -1 ||
          idString.indexOf(searchFilter) != -1)
            processed.push(url);
          break;
      }
    });
    return processed;
  };
});
```

Here is a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/xCwI2AURFpvb6xHgYHxS?p=preview

Comment: awesome, it's working exactly how I wanted it to be and the article is helpful as well. 
One further question though - combining these two filters is just the first step of what I ultimately want to build: 4 filters chained together (similar to the one here used by google analytics: http://awesomescreenshot.com/06b4q53x83
filter1: include/exclude
filter2: select column (as solved here)
filter3: different filter options (include, begins with, is equal to etc.)
filter4: input field (as solved here)
that given would you still recommend to define functions or better go with custom filters?

Comment: Could you give me an approximation of number of rows which will be displayed ? 
100 ?  500 ?  1000 ? more ?

Comment: sure - between 700 - 1000

Comment: Will you re-use those filters on other pages ? (separated or a combinaison)
If the response is yes then i recommend you to use filters.

Comment: it will be used on one main view, but might need a less complex version on another page. So I guess it would be better for me to use filters.
How could I rewrite the above function to a filter doing the same thing? I'm new to angular and a little help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please check the plunk link, i updated the code to use a filter, i added a second to let you see how you can pipe different filter. (only visible on plunkr)

Comment: thanks you so much for your help - wish I could upvote this again. checked the plunker, but the latest version (25) doesn't seem to work (the data table is almost empty)

Comment: That's because i chained 2 filters :), it was to show you how to chain 2 filters

Answer (score 1):

Check how this example straight from the angular page of a creating a custom filter. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

You can see here that you can create a filter that accepts 2 inputs, the actual object and a parameter. By passing the column name as parameter, you can narrow down your search for the correct rows.

Comment: thanks for that - i'm new to angular and not sure how to transfer there example to my case. could you possibly point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to write simple custom filter like this.

```
.filter('myfilter', function(){
  return function(input, column, text){
    if (!input || !column || !text) return input;
    return input.filter(function(item){
      var value = item[column.toLowerCase()];
      if (!value)return false;
      return value.indexOf(text)>-1;
    });
  };
});
```

You can use this filter in html.

```
ng-repeat="url in urls | myfilter:columnFilter:searchFilter"
```

[This is plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/rMvP7CVtvGMWEmRYP6Ll?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for that - I tried your plunker, but the searchFilter isn't working - any idea how to fix that?

Comment: In order to make sample as simple as possible, I use Array.filter to implement filter function.
If you use old browser which doesn't support Array.filter, this sample doesn't work fine.
My chrome(and Firefox) could work fine. Of course you need to change a little bit to support old browsers.

Comment: BTW this is [the new version of sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mc1PFmYtgP89HVR63dz6?p=preview) which uses underscore.js to support old browser. My IE9 works fine.