# AngularJS - filter table content considering only SOME of its fields

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-filter

I have a table built with `ng-repeat` this way:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="book in books | filter:searchText | orderBy: 'title'">
    <td>{{book.author}}</td>
    <td>{{book.title}}</td>
    <td>{{book.editor}}</td>
  </tr>
```

And `books` is an object which has more properties than the ones shown in the table. The research is simply implemented this way:

```
<label>Search: <input ng-model="searchText"/></label>
```

Now, what I need to do is apply the search filter ONLY to those data fields which are shown in the table. For example: let's suppose my data source `books` has these fields: `title`, `author`, `editor`, `year`, `isbn`, `description`. As it is now, if I type some words in the search input, the results are filtered considering ALL those fields, so I could visualize also some books containing that word in their description, resulting in some unclear search (the user has searched a word but can not see it in the results).

How can I apply the research only to the shown fields (I don't want to delete the unshown fields because I need them for other functions)?

Comment: may be help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849804/filter-by-multiple-columns-with-ng-repeat

Comment: this post may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273567/angular-filters-how-to-pre-filter-so-angular-filters-consider-only-a-partial-of/29274535#29274535

Comment: It looks like the answers on these questions are about filtering with an `AND` query (meaning if I search "a", it will filter for results that have an "a" on each field). What I need to do is filtering with an `OR` query (the results have an "a" in their title, author or editor, or two or three of them).

Comment: You can easily adapt the solutions provided to do what you need.